# Important user activity information has been removed

Tags: support, new-users, user-accounts, users

I apologize if this has been already answered. I did a search for this a few minutes ago but found nothing.

It appears that there have been recent changes to the user activity page and now, I am no longer able to see when a member was last active nor how long they have been a member. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place and it is available but moved to somewhere else?

If this info has gone (i.e. removed by "design") are there any sensible reasons for this disappearance?

OK, I've done a little more digging and [**HERE**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) is a link to what I regard as naff explanations for making the changes. That link takes you to SE.meta and, "the announcement" has so far received 211 downvotes. Just saying.

Personally I think it's meddling with stuff for the sake of meddling or justifying their own jobs.

The top answer **does suggest** a method to find when a person was last active but it doesn't show this to the nearest minute; it has a resolution of 1 day and, although somewhat useful, it's missing the point. So, go to a user profile and click on "network profile" (top right) then, click on accounts to see the "last seen" activity to the nearest day.

Comment: Member for __ years is also removed. Looks bad with lotta whitespace at the right.

Comment: @MituRaj I'm not bothered about the white space just the significant loss of useful info.

Comment: It looks like the member for x years has been returned to duty. Hurrah. Halfway there.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't much you can do if SE makes a change like this. They have probably had issues with people misusing the stats or complaints about lack of privacy, but who knows. I don't like the UI, I think it's worse than before. They should have left the text in the same place